# Jenkins не генерирует Allure-отчёт

Tags: jenkins, allure

Настроила тестовый джоб на дженкинсе, подключила allure, в папке target\allure-results появляются все необходимые файлы, однако на дженкинсе отчёт не генерируется, выплёвывает ошибку
*ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.exception.AllurePluginException: Can not generate Allure Report, exit code: 255.*
Локально всё отрабатывает нормально.
С чем может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

нашла решение - переустановила jenkins из .war, всё заработало